# Update WPF Datagrid bound to a Entity Framework View (SQL Server) After Updating the Underlying Entity (Table)

Tags: wpf, sql-server-2008, datagrid, entity-framework-4.1

I have a WPF datagrid which uses a `StaticResource` of a `CollectionViewSource` like so...

```
<Window.Resources>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="TransmittalsSource" />
...
<DataGrid x:Name="uxTransmittalDataGrid" Grid.Row="2"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TransmittalsSource}}"
...
```

In my code behind, I'm using a button's click event to assign the source for the `TransmittalsSource` like this...

```
var transmittalsQuery = from t in _db.TransmittalsViews
    select t; // I've remove the where clauses (filters) for readability.
((CollectionViewSource)Resources["TransmittalsSource"]).Source = 
    transmittalsQuery;
```

`TransmittalsViews` is a View object in the SQL Server database. I used View because I need to do some crosstab manipulation before presenting the data to the grid.

Now in another window, I am adding an item (basically updating one of the views column) on one of the base tables of `TransmittalsViews` called `Transmittals`.

```
_db.Transmittals.AddObject(_transmittal);
```

Now, even if I get the default view of the datagrid and call `Refresh()`, it's not working.

I'm thinking of getting the `DefaultView` of the datagrid and use 'AddNew` methods but seeing that the sources are different, I think it's not possible.

So how can I force refresh the datagrid which is based on a View object (SQL Server) after updating another entity (table) from which it was based? I know my coding is not that ideal at the moment so I will appreciate any comments on the techniques I've used as well. I'm just beginning to learn WPF :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get around this issue by setting the MergeOption to OverwriteChanges.

```
_db.TransmittalsViews.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```